# Formik InitialValue set by variable or state

Tags: reactjs, state, formik, react-select

I'm working on a project where I have to create some institutional relations objects, using formik and react-select. And these objects receive two specific properties, status_id and status_text, separately, but linked, and they are being passed when selected using the react-select lib, with status_id as value and status_text as label.

But on the POST and GET request only the status_id is returned, and I need the status_text so I can show the user which status they have, when viewing or editing the relation data. I was trying to make a get request and then filtering the data to only show the status_text according to its ID, with this function:

```
  const [statusText, setStatusText] = useState();

  const getStatusText = useCallback(async (id) => {
    const response = await getStatus();
    // eslint-disable-next-line array-callback-return
    const option = response.filter((t) => {
      if (id === t.value) return t.label;
    });
    const text = option[0].label;
    setStatusText(text);
    console.log(statusText);
  }, [statusText]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getStatusText(relation.status_id);
  }, [relation.status_id, getStatusText]);
```

Where relation.status_id is the Id, getStatus() is the service to get all statuses, and statusText is the state. This function works as intended, such as the console.log(statusText) returning the exact text I needed. But I am not able to use it with the formik initialValues. I am trying like this:

```
const initialValues = {
    selectedStatus: relation.status_id ? {
      value: relation.status_id || '',
      label: statusText || '',
    } : [],
  };
```

SelectedStatus is the variable I am using for the react-select component, and this relation.status_id comes as a prop from the previous page, relation containing all the data from the relation object. Since react-select works with label and values, I am setting its value as the status_id and am trying to set the label as the statusText state I filled before, but formik is not recognizing it. Is there any way to pass a variable or state to formiks initialValues?

Answer (score 0):

Update: It was only missing the enableReinitialize on the Formik component